# Select * from only one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Updated Question:

```
ALTER PROC Proc_Test
(
    @GrpBy as varchar(20) 
)
AS
Declare @TableTax table(
Taxid int,
TaxRange nvarchar(20),
MinLimit int,
MaxLimit int
)

SELECT t1.*     
FROM 
(
    SELECT  
        GroupBy = CASE @GrpBy 
                    WHEN 'JobGrade' THEN Employee.Grade                 
                    WHEN 'Tax Slab' THEN tblTax.TaxRange
                  END, (20 more calculated columns)
    FROM @TableTax AS tblTax, Employee
        LEFT JOIN Grade on Grade.Grade = Employee.Grade     
    WHERE
    Employee.Salary between tblTax.MinLimit and tblTax.Maxlimit     
    GROUP BY    
        CASE @GrpBy
                    WHEN 'JobGrade' THEN Employee.Grade                 
                    WHEN 'Tax Slab' THEN tblTax.TaxRange
                  END   
) AS t1
ORDER BY GroupBy
```

I want to order the result by TaxId. This order by would be applicable only in case when Tax Slab is selected in frontend.

Comment: How are the two tables related? also what are you ordering by exactly? does table `t2` have a column called `t2`

Comment: Is there a column linking t1 to t2?  In other words, which 2 rows from t2 are you interested in?

Comment: What do the tables look like?

Comment: Do not use implicit joins. THey are a sql antipattern. For instance I can't tell if you have mistakenly made a cross join or done one on purpose and people maintaining your code will not be able to tell either. This code was replaced by explicit joins in 1992, really it is time to stop using a poor technique and get with  the 21st century.

Comment: Why don't you drag the column names over from the object browser, the use of select * is iniefficient and can cause problems later on as the table changes. It is a SQL antipattern.

Comment: I just want to know how to exclude columns of one table. Can anyone help me in that ? Instead of marking all question or answers negative or answering sumthing which i already know ??

Comment: @RMN - If you want to exclude columns, just include the columns you need and that way - other columns would be excluded automatically. e.g. SELECT t1.Col1, t2.Col2 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.COl1 = t2.Col2. This way only col1 and col2 from t1 and t2 tables respectively would be selected and rest would be excluded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.JoinColumn = t2.JoinColumn
ORDER BY t2.SortColumn
```

Comment: While this is better answer, I downvoted it for the use of the SQL antiptatern of select *. JUst becasue someone asks for something deosn;t mean we should give it to him if it is a bad choice.

Answer (score 2):

You should add "where" clause

```
Select t1.* from t1, t2 where t1.somefield = t2.otherfield order by t2.sortfield
```